# Crystal Report : Nothing appears in crystal report

Tags: javascript, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am using `Crystal Report Version=13` in my Web Application using `Asp.Net`. My reports were working fine, i don't remember what changes i have made, due to which the report is not showing data, even `Design` is not shown of report. When i open report and refresh it, in `Fire Bug` i got the below error.

```
bobj.crv.stateManager.setComponentState('CrystalReportViewer1__UI',eval('('+document.getElementById('__CRYSTALSTATECrystalReportViewer1').value+')'));
```

Any one have experience of such type of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, i have disabled `ViewState` on my Application in web.config, by enabling it, its working.

```
<pages enableViewState="true" >
```