# No images and Javascript error on accessing Crystal Report in .NET 4.5 Web Application

Tags: javascript, crystal-reports, asp.net-4.5

We have a .NET 2.0 Web application that displays graphs using Crystal Reports.

We recently migrated our application to .NET 4.5 and everything is working fine except none of the crystal reports graphs are showing up. Instead I get a Javascript error and an empty container where a graph/image should have been present.

Line: `bobj.crv.stateManager.setComponentState('ctl00_DashboardControls_WebPartManager1_wp842781669_ctl01_ctl00__UI',eval('('+document.getElementById('__CRYSTALSTATEctl00$DashboardControls$WebPartManager1$wp842781669$ctl01$ctl00').value+')'))`

> Error: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined

We are using:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012
- OS: Windows 7 / 64-bit
- Browser: IE9
- Crystal report dll version: 13.0.2000.0
- We have all the required web.config entries including CrystalImageHandler.spx

I have tried various web config changes but haven't had any luck with them.

- http://scn.sap.com/thread/3538009
- [Crystal Report : Nothing appears in crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903231/crystal-report-nothing-appears-in-crystal-report)

I would like to hear if anyone else has faced a similar issue while migrating to .NET 4.5, if not then I'd really appreciate some help from Crystalreports dll users to guide me through troubleshooting. What can I look into first? Maybe CrystalImagehandler.aspx?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root-cause.

EnableViewState attibute of CrystalReportViewer was set to "False".
I cahnged it to "True" and missing javascript object that was causing the issue was inserted. My issue was thus resolved.